# Checkbox false value not passed to angular model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form with a checkbox that binds to ng-model property. When I check the checkbox the value is set in the model but when its unchecked, the key and value are never set at all so it fails api validation.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="post.title" placeholder="Post title..." />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="author">Author</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="post.author" placeholder="Your name" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="content">Content</label>
    <textarea ng-model="post.content"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="visible">Visible?</label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="post.is_visible" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
</div>


blogModule.controller('PostCreateController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'PostResource',
    function ($scope, $stateParams, PostResource) {
        $scope.post = new PostResource();
        $scope.addPost = function () {
            console.log($scope.post); // post.is_visible is undefined
            //$scope.post.$save();
        }
    }
]);
```

This is what the model looks like before it's saved:

```
{
    $resolved: true
    author: "asdag"
    content: "adfadsf"
    title: "adgadf"
    proto: ...
}
```

Why is post.is_visible undefined instead of being set to false? What can I do to make it set false?

Comment: normal form behavior ... unchecked checkboxes aren't sent to server in default browser submit process...so why would angular be any different? Sounds more like a server logic problem

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="post.is_visible"  ng-init="post.is_visible=false" />
```

Comment: won't change the issue if you toggle the checkbox on and off

Comment: i don't know whether this will help you, i have used something like this `ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false"`